# How to cryptsetup newly installed Ubuntu Server 18.10

Tags: server, encryption, 18.10, cryptsetup

I was wondering how to encrypt my harddrive on a newly installed Ubuntu Server 18.10. I tried this on Arch, which seemed to work fine, because I've done it during the installation fase. But with Ubuntu I have to setup cryptsetup, after booting the newly installed system.

I followed the follwing instructions https://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/

But everytime I try to configure cryptsetup I get the following error:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/sda3
WARNING: Device /dev/sda3 already contains a 'LVM2_member' superblock signature.

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/sda3 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda3:
Verify passphrase: 
Device /dev/sda3 is in use. Can not proceed with format operation.
Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).
$_
```

My setup:

```
Device      Start       End      Sectors      Size      Type
/dev/sda1    2048      4095         2048        1M      BIOS boot
/dev/sda2    4096   2101247      2097152        1G      Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3 2101248 209713151    207611904       99G      Linux filesystem
```

Any help is appreciated. I doubt the issue is my LVM setup, but who knows. I cannot find a website or blog with instructions, which explains this error. They all seem to work fine by just entering the cryptsetup command on the partition or harddisk.

One more question, wondering if it is possible (and advised) to run cryptsetup on the whole harddisk instead just the partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can't do it on the running system.

You need to configure your LUKS container (with cryptsetup) from the LiveCD/USB and then proceed to the installation by feeding those containers to the installer.

May be, it is better that you use a LVM install from the installer. It will automatically use LUKS/cryptsetup.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it using a live cd. In earlier versions I could choose for encrypted LVM volume, but 18.10 only shows a "Use An Entire Disk And Set Up LVM" option. So guess I actually have to use a live cd to prepare the partitions with LUKS. Thanks for the advice